# Find second occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have heard that JavaScript has a function called `search()` that can search for a string ( lets call it A ) in another string ( B ) and it will return the first position at which A was found in B.

```
var str = "Ana has apples!";
var n = str.search(" ");
```

The code should return 3 as its the first position in which the space was found in `str`.

And I was wondering if there is a function that can find the next spaces in my string.

For example I want to find the length of the first word in my string and I could easily do this If I knew the its starting position and its ending one.

If there is such a function, are there any better than it for such things?

Comment: You are looking for `indexOf()`, not `search()`.

Comment: You must want to use `str.indexOf(…)` (where `str` is your string).

Comment: `String.indexOf()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: `.indexOf()` gives you the index. `.includes()` will give you true or false. You can look up thse kind of things very easily on MDN or a different specification site, no need to post questions about basic syntax.

Comment: No, there is no pre-made function that will tell you all positions where a certain substring can be found.

Comment: Use `str.indexOf(' ', n)`, where `n` is the index at which to start the search. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method. It accepts the following arguments:

```
str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

So you can do this:

```js
var str = "Ana has apples!";
var pos1 = str.indexOf(" ");           // 3
var pos2 = str.indexOf(" ", pos1 + 1); // 7
console.log(pos2 - pos1 - 1);          // 3... length of the second word
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.indexOf(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will give you the first occurence of the `" "` (starting at 0):

```js
var str = "Ana has apples!";
var n = str.indexOf(" ");
console.log(n);
```

If you want all occurences, this can be achieved easily using a `RegExp` with a `while`:

```js
var str = "Ana has apples! A lot.";
var re = new RegExp(" ","ig");
var spaces = [];
while ((match = re.exec(str))) {
  spaces.push(match.index);
}

// Output the whole array of results
console.log(spaces);

// You can also access the spaces position separately:
console.log('1st space:', spaces[0]);
console.log('2nd space:', spaces[1]);
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

Or… you can use a `do {} while ()` loop:

```js
var str = "Ana has apples! A lot.";
var i = 0,
  n = 0;

do {
  n = str.indexOf(" ");
  if (n > -1) {
    i += n;
    console.log(i);
    str = str.slice(n + 1);
    i++;
  }
}
while (n > -1);
```

Then, you can make a function of it:

```js
var str = "Ana has apples! A lot.";

// Function
function indexsOf(str, sub) {
  var arr = [],
    i = 0,
    n = 0;

  do {
    n = str.indexOf(" ");
    if (n > -1) {
      i += n;
      arr.push(i);
      str = str.slice(n + 1);
      i++;
    }
  }
  while (n > -1);
  return arr;
}

var spaces = indexsOf(str, ' ')

// Output the whole array of results
console.log(spaces);

// You can also access the spaces position separately:
console.log('1st space:', spaces[0]);
console.log('2nd space:', spaces[1]);
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

Hope it helps.

Comment: While your algorithm works, all the index numbers are +1 in your result.

Comment: Well, @connexo I corrected that. But it was a wanted behaviour at first. Because the code was easier. (And I don't like that `.indexOf` starts at 0) :)

Answer (score 1):

Better for matching is to use `regex`. There is option like match **group** using group `'g'` flag

```js
var str = "Ana has apples  !";
var regBuilder = new RegExp(" ","ig");
var matched = "";
while((matched = regBuilder.exec(str))){
    console.log(matched + ", position : " +matched.index);
}

str = "Ana is Ana no one is better than Ana";
regBuilder = new RegExp("Ana","ig");
while((matched = regBuilder.exec(str))){
    console.log(matched + ", position : " +matched.index);
}
```

---

`'i'` flag used to **ignore case sensitive** 
You can check for other flags too [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const str = "Ana has apples!";

const spaces = str.split('')
                  .map((c, i) => (c === ' ') ? i : -1)
                  .filter((c) => c !== -1);

console.log(spaces);
```

Then you will all the spaces positions.

Comment: What about the space positions? This is what the question of the OP is about.

Comment: You are correct I misundestood OP question and edited my post.